# Trying to embed JS chess game into MVC app, unsure where to put CSS and JS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Trying to embed the content from

http://chessboardjs.com/

Into my MVC App. So far I have created a Controller called ChessGameController containing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace UserMcv.Controllers {

    public class ChessGameController : Controller {

        // GET: ChessGame
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }

    }

}
```

to return a view of:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

The downloaded file includes a CSS file, a Js file and Images of the chess pieces I don't know where to put?

Just to clarify, I would like to use:

`C:\Users\kealan.parr\Desktop\chessboardjs-0.3.0\js\chessboard-0.3.0.js` and

`C:\Users\kealan.parr\Desktop\chessboardjs-0.3.0\css\chessboard-0.3.0.css`

and the images of the chess pieces are at:

`C:\Users\kealan.parr\Desktop\chessboardjs-0.3.0\img\chesspieces\wikipedia`

Answer (score 0):

Put the files into your Project. For example into the `Content` and into the `Script` folder. Then you can achiev it with putting it into the `<head>` Tag:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/chessboard-0.3.0.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/chessboard-0.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I have done as you suggested, but I am getting a blank index page.

My view looks as thus


        @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<head>
    <title> Play chess </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/chessboard-0.3.0.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/chessboard-0.3.0.js"></script>
        </head>

And I added the scripts into Scripts and the CSS into content

I checked the names match up also

Comment: Try to call a function of the cheesboard.js. And be sure that it doesn't need other things, like jQuery for example.

Comment: Its merely appearing as text! Its not acting as a function :0

Is it a problem that I havent referenced the images of the pieces yet? The board should still be there I know thats CSS, but the pieces maybe affect everything?